# srcset shows the same file size in inspector panel on images (Next Image) where sizes and fill props are used

Tags: image, next.js

srcset shows the same file size in inspector panel on images (Next Image) where sizes and fill props are used - https://prnt.sc/xVoFV_q6_vcy

I guess it should be different sizes. If even I scale the width of browser I have the same behaviour.
my example
`<MediaLoader fill imageSrc = { imgSrc } mediaId = { card.id } mediaKind = { card.attributes.kind } overlay = { card.attributes.hidden ? 'hidden' : 'shadow-sm' } sizes = '10vw' onError = { () => setIsMediaLoaded(false) } onLoad = { () => setIsMediaLoaded(true) } onMediaIdChange = { () => setIsMediaLoaded(false) } />`

When I change sizes file size changes too. But I don't understand what src is used.